# Troubles with verifying a SQL request using a PDO prepare

Tags: php, html

I made a `html` login form called `loginForm.php` where we type last name, first name and password.
I'm using a `$_GET` method that act to `loginCheck.php`. In this page, I've build a `PHP PDO` and get back all the form variables.

Then I wrote a prepared request with the PDO and tried to compare the form variables and the tables fields values.

> loginForm.php

```html
<div class="formulaire">
<form action="./loginCheck.php" method="GET">
    <h3>Connectez-vous</h3>
    <div class="ligne">
        <div class="col25">
            <label for="nom"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Nom</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col75">
            <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" placeholder="ex: Martin">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ligne">
        <div class="col25">
            <label for="prenom"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Prénom</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col75">
            <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" placeholder="ex: Pierre">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ligne">
        <div class="col25">
            <label for="motDePasse"><i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i> Mot de Passe</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col75">
            <input type="password" id="mdp" name="mdp" placeholder="ex: motdepasse123">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ligne">
        <div class="col25">
            <label for="remember" style="font-size: 80%"><i class="fas fa-user-check"></i> Se souvenir de moi</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col75">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox"><span class="slider"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="ligne">
            <button class="valider" type="submit" formaction="./loginCheck.php" formmethod="get"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Se connecter</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div style="font-size: 50%">Pas encore de compte ? <a href="inscription">Inscrivez-vous</a></div>
```

> loginCheck.php

```php
<?php
/* Connexion à la base de données et gestion des erreurs */
try{
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=ckdhjqodomiform.mysql.db;dbname=ckdhjqodomiform;charset=UTF8", "ckdhjqodomiform", "D0miform01");
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Échec lors de la connexion : '.$e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_GET['nom']) and !empty($_GET['nom']) and isset($_GET['prenom']) and !empty($_GET['prenom']) and isset($_GET['motDePasse']) and !empty($_GET[''])) {

    $nom = $_GET['nom'];
    $prenom = $_GET['prenom'];
    $motDePasse = $_GET['motDePasse'];

    $requete = $dbc->prepare("SELECT nom, prenom motDePasse FROM COMPTE WHERE nom= :nom AND prenom= :prenom AND motDePasse= :motDePasse");
    $requete->bindParam(':nom', $nom);
    $requete->bindParam(':prenom', $prenom);
    $requete->bindParam(':motDePasse', $motDePasse);
    $requete->execute();
    $verif = $requete->fetchColumn();
}

    if($verif == 0) {
        $loginMessage = "Vos informations sont incorrectes.";
    } else {
        $sqlRes = $requete->fetch();
        $_SESSION['nom'] = $sqlRes['nom'];
        $_SESSION['prenom'] = $sqlRes['prenom'];
        $_SESSION['motDePasse'] = $sqlRes['motDePasse'];
        $loginMessage = "Connexion réussie";
    }
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./img/logo_icon.png" size="256x256">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/stylePrincipal.css"/><!-- Importation du style principal -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/responsiveBarStyle.css"/><!-- Importation du style du menu de navigation latèrale -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/53c23ad143.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><!-- Importation du kit FontAwesome pour des icônes stylisés -->
    
    
    <title>Domiform - Envoi du mail</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include "../modules/responsiveBar.php" ?>
    <header><img class="title" src="../img/title.png"></header>
    
    <main style="padding-bottom: 9%">
        <section id="mailConfirm">
           <p>
            <?php 
                echo $loginMessage;
                $delai= 4;
                $url = "./contacts.php#contactMail";
                header("Refresh: $delai ;url=$url");
                ?>
            </p>
           <p>Vous allez être redirigé sur la page d'accueil.</p>
        </section>
    </main>
    
    <?php include "../modules/footer.php" ?>
</body>
```

And actually, when I submit the form, it say that my informations are incorrect, but they are currently false, so maybe I'm blind and I'm missing the error, or either I'm in lack of knowledge and don't know how to fix my problem.

So I need some help, if someone will to help a soul.

Comment: You should not store passwords in plain text, they should be [hashed instead](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Hashed passwords will never match in a database, so you should first query for the nom/prenom, get the row, then use [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check it.

Comment: Hi, if you don't use hashed passwords, what's `!empty($_GET[''])` at the end of the if statement in loginCheck.php?

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei Oh, I didn't even notice it, it's supposed to be `!empty($_GET['motDePasse'])`. Thank you !

Comment: Your welcome! Good luck

Comment: @aynber Also, I don't understand why I should use hashed password if it never matches in a database. You confused me, so can you explain me more please ?

Comment: What he meant is they will never *directly* match (you can't hash user input and use that value in your `select` query). They have to be compared with `password_verify`.